# Can't determine why variable is unset (E: XPDY0002) in imported XQuery Module

Tags: variables, xquery, unset, exist-db

I'm trying to create a typeswitch in XQuery from TEXTCLASS to TEI. It's not a terribly difficult process, but it's tedious so I'm trying to automate as much of it as I can (and taking longer and learning more in the long run).

I'm using Oxygen 12 and Exist 1.4.1.

Right now I run transform-tei.xq which creates a handy dandy transformer using the functions in gen.xqm. After I added the function "convert-attr-default" (whose purpose is supposed to be taking a node's attributes and converting their names/values to lowercase), transform-tei.xq is throwing

"E [localhost] XPDY0002 : variable '$attr-name' is not set. [at line 58, column 18] [at line 58, column 18]"

and I can't determine why. I'm guessing I'm missing something pretty simple, as XQuery's the first language I've tried to teach myself and while the O'Reilly book is great, it's still a new type of learning.

```
xquery version '1.0';

(:  Module: transform-tei.xq
    Date: 24 06 2011
    Desc: Creates a module with functions to perform a basic transform to TEI on a specified xml document.
:)

declare option exist:serialize "method=text media-type=text/text";
import module namespace gen = "http://www.example.com/test/gen" at "xmldb:exist:///db/richmond/test-queries/gen.xqm";

let $doc := doc("/db/richmond/xml-for-typeswitch/wwa0005.0001.005.xml")
let $tags := gen:tags($doc)

let $config :=  
 <config>
   <modulename>text-tei</modulename>
   <namespace>http://www.example.com/test/text-tei</namespace>
 </config>
return 
  gen:create-module($tags, $config)
```

.

```
xquery version '1.0';

(:  Module: gen.xqm
    Note: Stolen/modified from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Generating_Skeleton_Typeswitch_Transformation_Modules#Generation_Function
    Date: 24 06 2011
    Desc: Provides functions to generate a list of all tags in a document and dynamically create a module to perform an identity transformation
:)

module namespace gen = "http://www.example.com/test/gen";

declare variable $gen:cr := "&#13;";

declare function gen:tags($docs as node()*) as xs:string * {
   for $tag in distinct-values ($docs//*/name(.))
   order by $tag
   return $tag
};

declare function gen:create-module($tags as xs:string*, $config as element(config) ) as element(module) {
let $modulename := $config/modulename/text()
let $prefix := $config/prefix/text()
let $pre:= concat($modulename,":",$prefix)
let $namespace := ($config/namespace,"http://mysite/module")[1]/text()
return
<module>
module namespace {$modulename} = "{$namespace}";
(: conversion module generated from a set of tags 

:)
<function>
declare function {$pre}convert($nodes as node()*) as item()* {{ {$gen:cr}
  for $node in $nodes
  return 
     typeswitch ($node)
       {for $tag in $tags
        return 
           <s>case element({$tag}) return {$pre}{replace($tag,":","-")}($node)
           </s>
       }
       default return 
         {$pre}convert-default($node)
  }};
</function>

<function>
declare function {$pre}convert-default($node as node()) as item()* {{ {$gen:cr}
  $node
  }};
</function>

<function>
declare function {$pre}convert-attr-default($attr as attribute()*) as item()* {{ {$gen:cr}
  for $upper-attr in $attr
  let $attr-name := fn:node-name($upper-attr)
  let $attr-val := fn:data($upper-attr)

  return
    attribute { $attr-name } { $attr-val }
  }};
</function>

{for $tag in $tags
 return 
   <function>
declare function {$pre}{replace($tag,":","-")}($node as element({$tag})) as item()* {{ {$gen:cr}
  element {lower-case($tag)} {{
     {$pre}convert-attr-default($node/@*),
     {$pre}convert($node/node()) 
     }}{$gen:cr}
}};
   </function>
}

</module>
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, variable `$attr-name` appears to be defined three lines above its reference. A closer look however reveals that the apparent definition is in literal element content of the constructed `function` element. From within that element content, a single curly brace escapes into expression mode, where the reference is.

Thus the definition is in the generated query, whereas the reference is in the generating query. It will be necessary to align the curly braces appropriately, to get both into the same scope. Note that there are two curly braces opening the generated function, which is the notation for a single curly brace to appear in element content.